# pyodbc.cursor attribute is still read only when converted to string

Tags: python, pyodbc

Pyodbc.cursor is being used to extract a data from a SQL table:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=BadgerServer;'
                      'Database=tracking;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
table_name = 'Badgers'
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Get out the SQL query
fd = open('Badgers_joined.sql', 'r')
sqlFile = fd.read()
fd.close()
query_list = sqlFile.split(';') # all SQL commands (split on ';')
query = query_list[0] # Extract the first query.

cursor.execute(query) #Doesn't return the headings.
```

This executes correctly. I also want the column headings and so use the following:

```
columnHeadings = []
for column in cursor.description:
    columnHeading = str(column[0])
    columnHeadings.append(columnHeading)
```

Column headings extracted from the cursor object are explicitly converted to strings before appending to a list. I then create a pandas dataframe from the cursor and attempt to apply the column headings:

```
neckinj_Table = pd.DataFrame(cursor)
neckinj_Table.columns = columnHeadings
```

However this returns an error (for the line where column headings are applied):

```
AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Cursor' object attribute 'columns' is read-only
```

I do not understand why this is as I have forced each column heading into a string and appended to a list. Running

```
print(type(columnHeadings))
```

Gives

```
<class 'list'>
```

Rather than a pyodbc.Cursor object.

What is the error in my code or my approach?

P.S. The pd.read_sql method cannot be used as the type of database connection I have is not supported.